# Entity Framework EDMX to Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have an application using EF5 modeling with EDMX and I have much more experience and affinity with Code First. Does anyone have any idea / tutorial on how to migrate from EDMX Code First without changing the database and entity classes?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate Code First classes from existing database. For this you should create new ADO.NET EDM project and choose "Code First from database" option. After that you choose your DB instance and tables for generating DTOs.

More details in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx